# How to return a different Razor Page without redirect?

Tags: razor-pages

I am porting a Asp.Net MVC application to Razor Pages.

In some of the controllers of the MVC application it makes use of `return View("someOtherView", someModelForOtherView);`

How do I port this to Razor Pages?
What I need to do is to transfer the request over to another Razor Page and pass the prepared PageModel to it (the other page does not need to execute `OnMethod()` but simply render its html.
Or, in other words, I only need to swap the template file that should be rendered with another one.

I cannot use `Redirect` as there must not be another roundtrip via the browser.

Comment: I opened an issue on github https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/8002

Answer (score 11):

I doubt this is (easily) possible. From the [github request](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/8002) that Lerner linked above, it's noted Razor Pages weren't designed to do that.

The closest workaround I was able to achieve was to turn my destination Razor Page into a View. (Hence, no code-behind.) Obviously that will only be possible if your destination page is never directly accessed via URL. For example, if you want to redirect to `/Pages/MyPage`, and you still need to be able to access the url `http://example.com/MyPage`, this won't work.

But, say all you want is a generic error or status page. Those don't have to be directly-accessible through URL. This works well for that.

Here's a couple extension methods on `PageModel` to do it, one that accepts models and one that doesn't:

```
public static ViewResult View(this PageModel pageModel, string viewName) {
    return new ViewResult() {
        ViewName = viewName,
        ViewData = pageModel.ViewData,
        TempData = pageModel.TempData
    };
}

public static ViewResult View<TModel>(this PageModel pageModel, string viewName, TModel model) {
    var viewDataDictionary = new ViewDataDictionary<TModel>(new EmptyModelMetadataProvider(), new ModelStateDictionary()) {
        Model = model
    };
    foreach (var kvp in pageModel.ViewData) viewDataDictionary.Add(kvp);

    return new ViewResult {
        ViewName = viewName,
        ViewData = viewDataDictionary,
        TempData = pageModel.TempData
    };
}
```

*FYI, the reason for having to recreate the view dictionary is because the one in your `pageModel` is going to have a model type specific to the current Page, not to the View you're directing to, and you can't change the Model within a ViewDataDictionary to a different type. MVC would complain and throw an exception.*

Usage:

```
public IActionResult OnGet(string id) {
    // check if id is good here     
    if (idIsNoGood) return this.View("InvalidId", new ErrorModel...);
    else {
        return Page();
    }
}
```

The above will look for `InvalidId.cshtml` view, which can be in the same folder as your page, the root `/Pages/` folder, or `/Pages/Shared/`. And it'll still use your Layout too, like any other page.

Just make sure your cshtml file doesn't have a `@page` directive at the top; this won't work for a Razor page, only a View.

Example InvalidId.cshtml:

```
@model MyProject.Models.ErrorModel
<h1>Invalid Request</h1>
<p>@Model.Message</p>
```

Comment: thank you - you are a life saver - I've spent 6 hours trying to resolve this, slightly different - I had a razor page that needed to return an Error MVC view - your solution works for that :-)